# Download the file from web using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android

Any one knows how to download a file from web using the DefaultHttpClient in android?
I tried most of the possible options, is openurl connection but I need to use the DefaultHttpClient

Thanks in advance

Comment: is this image coming from your server. If yes then ask then to send it as base64 string value and convert that base64 string to image in your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give one example it helps u definately 
     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

```
 // Prepare a request object
 HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/");

 // Execute the request
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

 // Examine the response status
 System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

 // Get hold of the response entity
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

 // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
 // to worry about connection release
 if (entity != null) {
     InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
     try {

         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                 new InputStreamReader(instream));
         // do something useful with the response
         System.out.println(reader.readLine());

     } catch (IOException ex) {

         // In case of an IOException the connection will be released
         // back to the connection manager automatically
         throw ex;

     } catch (RuntimeException ex) {

         // In case of an unexpected exception you may want to abort
         // the HTTP request in order to shut down the underlying
         // connection and release it back to the connection manager.
         httpget.abort();
         throw ex;

     } finally {

         // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
         instream.close();

     }

     // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
     // shut down the connection manager to ensure
     // immediate deallocation of all system resources
     httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
 }
```